# Swapping out Onan generator on a motor home

Tags: electrical, wiring, generator

I have a non-functioning 120V Onan generator on a motorhome.  To replace it with another Onan that is 240V, do I need to change any wiring to the vehicle or can I rewire it in-place the same way?

The new generator is compatible with the previous one in terms of space/framing.

Comment: STOP using all capitol letters, It is annoying and unnecessary. This is not a Home improvement DIY question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is about a motorhome and not home diy.

Comment: @AlaskaMan  Dude you are triggered!   I'm an old mainframe programmer and all we had was all UPPER CASE!  Yeah, isherwood  will probably snip me for this,  but geeze.

Comment: Not voting to close. it's still a home.  the 120/240 wiring follows the same principles

Comment: there will be some changes, possibly minor,  does it have an inlet for a grid connection ("shore power"), what sort of plug does it use, photos of the inside of the fuse/breaker box and the generator connection would help too.

Comment: This should stay open -- mains wiring on RVs/motorhomes is within the NEC's scope

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing generator connection wiring and AC loadcenter in your RV?